# Corollary 1.6 in Mumford's Geometric Invariant Theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, geometric-invariant-theory

I do not understand fully the proof of Corollary 1.6 from Mumford's [Geometric Invariant Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540569633) (§3: Linearization of an invertible sheaf, p 35):

*Corollary 1.6*
$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}\DeclareMathOperator\Pic{Pic}$Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group $G$ acting on an
algebraic variety over $k$, which is proper over $k$.
(Mumford's variety is a scheme $X/k$ such that
$\overline{X}= X \times \Spec(\overline{k})$ is irreducible
and closed; cf. Chap 0.) Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible
sheaf on $X$.
Then if $ \overline{X} $ is a normal variety, some tensor
power $\mathcal{L}^n$ of $\mathcal{L}$ is always linearizable.

**Proof.** According to a result of Chevalley [Ch 10],
in this case all components of $\Pic(X/k) $ are proper
over $k$, hence all reduced components are Abelian varieties.
Therefore the connected linear group $G$, being birational to
projective space as a variety (?), must act trivially on
$\Pic(X/k) $ (Why that's true? comp. 1st question?)
[…and finally claim follows from previous
Prop 1.5 which states that some power $\mathcal{L}^n$
of $\mathcal{L}$ is $G$-linearizable iff
some multiple $n \lambda $ of $\lambda \in \Pic(X/k)(k)$
is fixed by $G$, where the $k$-point $\lambda$ of $\Pic(X/k)$
is defined by $\mathcal{L}$.]

Questions:
Why is $G$ as connected linear group birational to
projective space?

And why the above leads to the consequence that $G$ acts trivially
on $\Pic(X/k) $? We can reduce it to the question
why the action of every connected linear group
on an Abelian variety is trivial.

A Remark: Mumford nowhere describes this action of $G$ on
$ \Pic(X/k)$ in explicit terms, so I assume he means the
most natural one, i.e. for $S \to \Spec(k)$ the action
of a geometric point $\alpha \in G$ on $X$ induces an action
on $X \times_k S$ via $\alpha \times 1_S$ and this one acts on

$$ \Pic(X/k)(S) = \{ \mathcal{M} \text{ invertible sheaf 
on } X \times_k S \} / \{ \text{ inv. sheaves of the form }
p^*_S(\mathcal{K}) \text{ for } \mathcal{K} \text{ invertible on }
S \}  $$

via taking pullpacks $\mathcal{M} \mapsto (\alpha \times 1_S)^*\mathcal{M}$. Is it correct?

[Ch10] Chevalley, C: [Sur la théorie de la variété de Picard](https://doi.org/10.2307/2372968).

Comment: A linear group is rational (:= birational to affine space) over $\bar{k}$, but this is sufficient here: any morphism of a rational variety onto an abelian variety is trivial. So the orbits of $G$ acting on $\operatorname{Pic}(X/k) $ are trivial.

Comment: ohh, of course I see. Thank you!

Comment: I think that some Cayley transform trick makes them birational to projective space.

Comment: in the remark in last paragraphI made a guess as to how I think the action of $G$ on $\text{Pic }(X/k)$ would work in detail. Is it correct or is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is correct — this is just the definition of the Pic functor.

Comment: I noticed on your [new question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434172/proposition-1-5-in-mumfords-geometric-invariant-theory) that you had copied and pasted some of the structure from this post, but changed the link to GIT I originally [edited in](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/433970/5) to this post.  I wondered why, and it turns out … although that is the official [MSN link](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1304906), it doesn't exist at all!  I am very sorry for pasting the wrong link without checking.  I have edited for consistency.

Comment: It should be noted that this part of Mumford's book has been made obsolete by Sumihiro's  "Equivariant Completion" paper. In particular, it is shown that the properness assumption is superfluous. See also our survey "Local properties of algebraic group actions" for an elementary account.