# Proposition 1.5 in Mumford's Geometric Invariant Theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory, picard-group

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator\Pic{Pic}\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}\DeclareMathOperator\pr{pr}$I have some problems to understand the proof of *Proposition 1.5* from Mumford's [Geometric Invariant Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540569633), p 34:

*Corollary 1.5*
Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group acting on an algebraic
variety $X$, that is proper over $k$ (in the book a variety is a
scheme $X/k$ such that
$\overline{X}= X \times \Spec(\overline{k})$ is irreducible
and reduced). Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible
sheaf on $X$, and let $[\mathcal{L}]$ the class regarded as the $k$-rational point of the
Picard scheme $\Pic(X/k)$ associated to $\mathcal{L}$.
Then some power $\mathcal{L}^n$ is $G$-linearizable if and only if
some multiple
$[\mathcal{L}]^n$ of $[\mathcal{L}] $ is left fixed by induced $G$-action
on $ \Hom_k(\Spec(k), \Pic (X/k))$.

(at this point one should remark that in the book this left action
by $G$ on $\mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}(k)$ is not explained in explicit terms.
In the substantively similar question [Corollary 1.6 in Mumford's Geometric Invariant Theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433970/corollary-1-6-in-mumfords-geometric-invariant-theory) I made a remark how I think this
action might work in detail).

[Second important *remark* before
we dip into the proof:
Recall that more less by [definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Picard+scheme) of the Picard functor is given by

$$ \mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}(S) :=  H^0(G, R^1p_{1*} (\mathcal{O}_{S \times X}^*) =  \\
 \{ \mathcal{M} \text{ invertible sheaf 
on } X \times_k S \} / \{ \text{ inv. sheaves of the form }
p^*_S(\mathcal{K}) \text{ for } \mathcal{K} \text{ invertible on }
S \}. $$

The proof uses [cp *Chap. 0, §5, (d)*] the fact that the Picard functor is "almost"
representable, that means precisely there exists a $k$-scheme
$\Pic(X/k)$ representing the associated
functor $\text{Hom}( \ , \Pic(X/k))$ which *contains* the
Picard functor  $\mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}$
in the sense that for any $k$-scheme $S$ there is a functorial
inclusion

$$ \iota_S: \mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}(S) \hookrightarrow \Hom_k(S,\Pic(X/k)).  $$

In general that's a proper inclusion.
The equality only holds if $X \times_k S$ admits a section over $S$.

> **The Proof.** The only if is clear. Conversely, suppose $[\mathcal{L}]^n$
> is left fixed by $G$. Then the claim  is first that for some $m$, the
> two pullback sheaves $\sigma^*(\mathcal{L}^{nm})$ and
> $p_2^*(\mathcal{L}^{nm})$ (induced by the action and projection maps
> $\sigma, p_2: G \times X \to X $ on $ G \times X $ are isomorphic.
> To see this, consider the see-saw exact sequence [Rem.: I never saw the term see-saw sequence. I think that is just the exact part of Leray–Serre  spectral sequence for higher image sheaf]:

$$  0 \to H^1(G, \mathcal{O}_G^*) \to 
H^1(G \times X, \mathcal{O}_{G \times X}^*)  \to
H^0(G, R^1p_{1*} (\mathcal{O}_{G \times X}^*).$$

> Since $H^1(G, \mathcal{O}_G^*)$ is a finite group (Seminaire
> Chevalley, [9], 5-21), it is enough to show that the image of
> $\sigma^*(\mathcal{L}^n) \otimes p_2^*(\mathcal{L}^n)^{-1}$
> in $H^0(G, R^1p_{1*} (\mathcal{O}_{G \times X}^*)$ is zero. But,
> by the functorial definition of $\Pic (X/k)$
> (cf Chap. 0, §5, (d), page 23)

$$ \mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}(G) = H^0(G, R^1p_{1*} (\mathcal{O}_{G \times X}^*) \subset
\Hom_k(G, \Pic (X/k)).   $$

> But, as in the proof of proposition 1.4, it holds
> $H^0(G \times X, \mathcal{O}_{G \times X}^*)  \cong
> H^0(G, \mathcal{O}_G^*)$ and the latter is just $k* \times M$, where
> $M$ is the set of characters, i.e., $\Hom(G, \mathbb{G}_m)$.
> *Choose an isomorphism*
> $\phi: \sigma^*(\mathcal{L}^{nm}) \to p_2^*(\mathcal{L}^{nm})$, which
> is the identity on $\{e\} \times X$.
> [The rest of the proof verifies the cocycle condition
> $p^*_{23} \phi \circ (1_G \times \sigma)^* = (m \times 1_x)^* \phi $, that's fine .]

The **question** is why the assumption that the class
$[\mathcal{L}^n] \in \Hom_k(\Spec(k), \Pic (X/k))$
is fixed by $G$-action, implies that
the pullback sheaves $\sigma^*(\mathcal{L}^{nm})$ and
$p_2^*(\mathcal{L}^{nm})$ are isomorphic, or as remarked that's equivalent to to the question why
the images of classes $[\sigma^*(\mathcal{L}^{n})]$ and
$[p_2^*(\mathcal{L}^{n})]$ in
$ H^0(G, R^1p_{1*} (\mathcal{O}_{G \times X}^*)) \subset
\Hom_k(G, \Pic (X/k))   $
are identical?

To rephrase it in other terms, the maps $\sigma, p_2: G \times X \to X $, which are given on geometric points by $(g,x) \mapsto g \cdot x$, respectively  $(g,x) \mapsto x$, map the classes $[\mathcal{M}] \in \mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}(k) $ to classes in $\mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}(G)$ via taking  $[\mathcal{M}]$ to the pullback $[\sigma^*\mathcal{M}]$, respectively  $[p_2^*\mathcal{M}]$.
How do these operations by $\sigma, p_2$ look like in *explicit* terms as maps between $ \Hom(\Spec(k), \Pic(X/k))$ and $\Hom(G, \Pic(X/k))$? Especially how to construct explicitly
from the pullback of $[\mathcal{L}]^n$ by $\sigma$ and $p_2$
elements in $\Hom_k(G, \Pic (X/k)) $ representing
the classes of the images of
$\sigma^*(\mathcal{L}^{n})$ and
$p_2^*(\mathcal{L}^{n})$?

Pictorally, the action and projection morphisms $\sigma, \pr_X$  should induce following diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}(k) @>{\iota_k}  >> \Hom(\Spec(k), \Pic(X/k)) \\
@VV\sigma^*, p_2^*V  @VVf_{\sigma^*}, f_{\pr_X^*}V  \\
\mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}(G) @>{\iota_G}>> \Hom(G, \Pic(X/k))
\end{CD}
$$

and I'm interested in the explicit structure of the right vertical maps $f_{\sigma^*}, f_{\pr_X^*}:
\Hom(\Spec(k), \Pic(X/k)) \to 
\Hom(G, \Pic(X/k))$ making the diagram commutative
with respect $\sigma^*, \pr_X^*$ on the left and what they do with $[\mathcal{L}^n] \in \Hom_k(\Spec(k), \Pic (X/k))$.

My conjecture is  that the image of
$p_2^*(\mathcal{L}^{n})$ in
$\Hom_k(G, \Pic (X/k)) $ should represent a constant map with image be the $k$-point
$[\mathcal{L}^n]$, while $\sigma^*(\mathcal{L}^{n})$ the
orbit map of $[\mathcal{L}^n]$ induced by the action of $G$ on $k$-valued points of $  \Pic (X/k)$. This would suggest that $f_{\sigma^*}$ and $f_{\pr_X^*}$ should be explicitly given by

$$ [x] \mapsto f_{\sigma^*}([x]) := (g \mapsto g \cdot [x])  $$

and respectively

$$ [x] \mapsto f_{\pr_X^*}([x]) := (g \mapsto [x])  $$

i.e. the constant map, where $[x]: \Spec(k) \to \Pic(X/k)$
is any geometric $k$-point of $\Pic(X/k)$ and $ g \cdot [x]:=  [g^*x]$ the induced action on Picard group via pullback. Having this,  we assumed $G$ to fix $[\mathcal{L}^n]$, therefore these the images of $[\mathcal{L}^n]$  by these maps would coinside as elements in
$\Hom_k(G, \Pic (X/k)) $ and should give isomorphic
line bundles over $G \times X$.

Therefore if the  $f_{\sigma^*}$, $f_{\pr_X^*}$ would be given like I conjecture, this would be consistent with the tacitly used claim in the proof that $[\sigma^*(\mathcal{L}^{n})]$ and $ [p_2^*(\mathcal{L}^{n})]$ are identical as elements in $\mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}(G)  \subset
\Hom_k(G, \Pic (X/k))$. But I not see how to verify that $f_{\sigma^*}$, $f_{\pr_X^*}$ have this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fist part of the proof of 1.5 may be rephrased as follows. The hypothesis that $[\mathcal{L}^n]$ is fixed by the $G$-action exactly means that for all $g \in G$, there is an isomorphism:
$$ \sigma^* \mathcal{L}^n \big|_{\{g\} \times X} \simeq p_2^* \mathcal{L}^n|_{\{g\} \times X}.$$ Put differently, for all $g \in G$, there is an isomorphism:

$$\sigma^* \mathcal{L}^n \otimes \left(p_2^* \mathcal{L}^n \right)^{-1} \big|_{\{g\} \times X} \simeq \mathcal{O}_X.$$
By the Seesaw Theorem, this means that $\sigma^* \mathcal{L}^n \otimes \left(p_2^* \mathcal{L}^n\right)^{-1}$ is the pull-back of a line bundle on $G$. But a Theorem of Chevalley implies $H^{1}(G, \mathcal{O}_{G}^*)$ is finite, hence $\sigma^* \mathcal{L}^n \otimes \left(p_2^* \mathcal{L}^n \right)^{-1}$ is torsion and we are done.

Comment: this argument I understand. but do you maybe know if it's also possible to find out the explicit form of the morphisms $G \to \text{Pic}(X/k)$ on the right side which corresponds to the classes $ [ \sigma^*(\mathcal{L}^{n})]$ and $ [ p_2^*(\mathcal{L}^{n})]$ in $ \mathcal{Pic}_{X/k}(G)  $?

Comment: @JustusC : your conjecture about the morphisms $f_{\sigma}$ and $f_{pr^*_X}$ should be correct. I think you just have to use the fact that the morphism $i_G$ sends a line bundle $L$ on $X \times G$ to the map $g \longrightarrow L|_{\{g\} \times X}$ and the fact that the diagram is commutative.

Comment: could you give a sketch (if that's not too long) or a reference where I can look up a proof of that $i_G$ is given that way? It looks of course heuristically plausible, but I nowhere found literature cointaining the formal proof which affirms this.

Comment: @JustusC : I think i may be able to do that. But I would need to write commutative diagrams, which I can not do in a comment. It will be easier if you ask a separate question.

Comment: thank you a lot. I will post it next day

Comment: [here in mse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582822/embedding-of-picard-functor-into-texthom-k-textpicx-k) I posted it